# Javascript - Determine if any scoped references in object

Tags: javascript, json, object-type

I execute some function and get a return value. This value could be anything (string, array, object, reference, function). I then pass this result along using `JSON.stringify`.

Now, the functions and references don't do me much good in the scope they're being delivered to, so the whole "to string, eval" method isn't much use. I'm going to store them in a local array and just pass along an ID to reference them by later. But, I do go ahead and send string data, arrays, and objects (in the "associated array" sense of javascript objects) as those all play very nicely with `JSON.stringify`.

I'm already using `try... JSON.stringify() catch` to do this with recursive objects (which `JSON.stringify` errors on.) But that doesn't account for anything else mentioned above.

What is the most efficient way to check if an value contains a function?

And not

```
typeof foo === "function"
```

Because the return might be

```
["foo", "bar", ["foo", "bar"], function(){...something}]
```

I don't want to pick apart each individual piece's type either, just return on the whole whether there's ANY functions/objects that cannot be safely stringified. I could probably work out how to loop and check each individual value, but if there's a shortcut or more efficient method someone can think of, I'd like to hear it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refining welcome and appreciated!

```
//your favorite object length checking function could go here
$.objectLength = (function(){
    //ie<9
    if (typeof Object.keys === "undefined" ){
        return function(o){
            var count = 0, i;
            for (i in o) {
                if (o.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        };

        //everyone else
    } else {
        return function(o){
            return Object.keys(o).length;
        }
    }
})();

//comparing our two objects
$.checkMatch = function(a, b){

    //if they're not the same length, we're done here. (functions exist, etc)
    if (typeof a !== typeof b || typeof a === "object" && typeof b === "object" && a && b && $.objectLength(a) !== $.objectLength(b)){
        return false;

    //if they are the same length, they may contain deeper objects we need to check.
    } else {
        var key;
        for (key in a){

            //make sure it's not prototyped key
            if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)){

                //if it doesn't exist on the other object
                if (!b.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                    return false;

                //if this an object as well
                } else if (typeof a[key] === "object"){

                    //check for a match
                    if (!$.checkMatch(a[key], b[key])){
                        return false;
                    }

                //then check if they're not equal (simple values)
                } else if (a[key] !== b[key]){
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
//...stuff

//catch recursive objects in parameters
var good = true, sendObject = {"ourobject", "values"}, finalSendObject;
//try to stringify, which rejects infinitely recursive objects
try {
    finalSendObject = JSON.stringify(sendObject);
} catch(e){
    good = false;
}
//if that passes, try matching the original against the parsed JSON string
if (good && sendObject !== JSON.parse(finalSendObject)){
    good = $.checkMatch(sendObject, JSON.parse(finalSendObject));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**This will not work**

But I will leave it up for anyone who thinks of trying it. Working solution coming shortly.

30 seconds later, I figure it out myself.

String it, parse it. If anything changed, it wont be equal to itself.

```
var checkParse = function(obj){
    return obj === JSON.parse(JSON.strigify(obj));
}
```

Comment: The return value will always be `false`. `checkParse({}); // false`

Comment: Testing it out now. How do you figure though? If it's say... a string, and I stringify then parse it, it should be the same.

Comment: Same content, different object.

Comment: How does that fail a comparison? It's not looking for the same object, it's looking for an equal object.

Comment: `JSON.parse` returns a new object which will not evaluate to the same input object

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. Are you calling this on primitives or objects or both? Called on a `string`, it'll work. On an object it won't. For objects, it's as I said above, same content, different object. Different object means not equal.

Comment: Both. So maybe. Like I said I'm setting it up to test it in my scenario now. Made sense to me though...

Comment: Two references to objects are only equal if they point to the same object. `JSON.parse` returns a new object, which may or may not have the same attributes as `obj`. Either way, it is a different object, so it will never be equal to `obj`.

Comment: You are correct. I will adjust accordingly. I still think this path may be fruitful...

Comment: New answer posted. Leaving this for reference in case anyone has the same thought.